# Delete worksheet in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macros that generates a number of workbooks. I would like the macros, at the start of the run, to check if the file contains 2 spreadsheets, and delete them if they exist.

The code I tried was:

```
If Sheet.Name = "ID Sheet" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If

If Sheet.Name = "Summary" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Sheet.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End If
```

This code is returning an error:

> run time error #424, object required.

I probably have the wrong formatting, but if there is an easier way to do this, it would be very useful.

Comment: You need to loop and then call `Sheet(i).Name`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub SheetKiller()
    Dim s As Worksheet, t As String
    Dim i As Long, K As Long
    K = Sheets.Count

    For i = K To 1 Step -1
        t = Sheets(i).Name
        If t = "ID Sheet" Or t = "Summary" Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Sheets(i).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

*NOTE:*

Because we are **deleting**, we run the loop *backwards.*

Answer (score 12):

Try this code:

```
For Each aSheet In Worksheets

    Select Case aSheet.Name

        Case "ID Sheet", "Summary"
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            aSheet.Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    End Select

Next aSheet
```

Answer (score 9):

You could use `On Error Resume Next` then there is no need to loop through all the sheets in the workbook.

With `On Error Resume Next` the errors are not propagated, but are suppressed instead. So here when the sheets does't exist or when for any reason can't be deleted, nothing happens. It is like when you would say : *delete this sheets, and if it fails I don't care.* Excel is supposed to find the sheet, you will not do any searching.

*Note: When the workbook would contain only those two sheets, then only the first sheet will be deleted.*

```
Dim book
Dim sht as Worksheet

set book= Workbooks("SomeBook.xlsx")

On Error Resume Next

Application.DisplayAlerts=False 

Set sht = book.Worksheets("ID Sheet")
sht.Delete

Set sht = book.Worksheets("Summary")
sht.Delete

Application.DisplayAlerts=True 

On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: an explanation of this code in the answer and why it is a good solution would be really helpful...

Comment: @DrCord what do you want to explain? It is self explanatory. To be honest I don't know if this is a good solution, it is just another approach to do it. Based on the small amount of up votes I think that this is probably not good solution. Nevertheless in this case it could be simpler to let excel do the search and just ignore the exceptions which could be thrown when the sheet can't be deleted. But one must be careful with resume-next, OK?

Comment: how about why using `On Error Resume Next` prevents the need to loop through all the sheets in the WB? That isn't obvious to me why that works as a fairly new excel macro programmer...

Comment: @DrCord With on error resume next the errors are not propagated, but are suppressed instead. So here when the sheet does't exist or when for any reaso can't be deleted, nothing happens. It is like when you would say : delete this sheets, and if it fails i don't care. Execl is supposed to find the sheet, you will not do any searching.

Comment: Great, that's what I thought was the point, thanks for the explanation. It helps me to be sure and helps other future SO users to decide if this code will help them solve their issue. :D tyvm!

Answer (score 3):

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Delete
Worksheets("Sheet2").Delete
```

Answer (score -1):

try this within your if statements:

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Worksheets(“Sheetname”).Delete
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: This will throw a "subscript out of range" error if Sheetname does not exist.

Comment: Of course it will, but "Sheetname" has to be changed to the actual name of the sheet you want to delete. So if you want to delete Sheet1 Sheetname will become "Sheet1"

Comment: OP has specifically stated he wants to check if the sheets exist, so your assumption that the sheets will always exist is not valid. Your edit "for those that don't understand coding" is not appropriate.

Comment: @Eddy, I misunderstood your remark there. Sorry for that. But as his original code contained IF statements there is no need to encounter a "subscript out of range" as the statement will only run when the IF encounters the sheetname. Emphasized that in my answer.