# Delete a specific worksheet from .xlsm file

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to delete a worksheet using the following code.  Throwing an "Object required" error on the delete line.  I have tried many variations on this line, i.e., s.delete,  sheets.s.delete, worksheets.delete, etc.

```
Dim s As Worksheet
'Look for existing sheets named "For Export
'If found, delete existing sheet
For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If s.Name = "For Export" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        Workbook.Worksheets.Item(s.Name).Delete        
    End If
Next s
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete worksheet in Excel using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475376/delete-worksheet-in-excel-using-vba)

Comment: Is `For Export` the only sheet left in the workbook? There always need to be at least one worksheet in the workbook. Otherwise, `s.Delete` should do it.

Comment: s.delete is the original command, but was getting an error.  It is not the only sheet in the book

Comment: Change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook` (assuming the workbook where the code runs is where the sheet is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
Sub deleteWorksheet()
    Dim s As Worksheet, t As String
    Dim i As Long, K As Long
    K = Sheets.Count

    For i = K To 1 Step -1
        t = Sheets(i).Name
        If t = "For Export" Then
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                Sheets(i).Delete
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
Sub poiuyt()
    Dim s As Worksheet
    For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
      If s.Name = "For Export" Then
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            s.Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
      End If
    Next s
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

```
For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
        If s.Name = ws_name Then
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            Sheets(ws_name).Delete
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
            Exit For
        End If
Next s
```

Comment: You can also explain what you did there.